# libcurl does not support compression

Tags: curl, libcurl

libcurl supports decompression (like `gzip` and `deflate`).But I remak that it des not support compression.
this is wierd.

why it does not support compression too ?

Answer (score 0):

Acording to [curl developer Daniel Stenberg](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2011-05/0004.html)

> there's no way to automatically do compression of HTTP requests.

Apache allows [Input Decompression](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html), but

> Few browsers have the ability to gzip request bodies

That may be the reason behind it.

Comment: Right, not of the upload part, but the client can still automatically decompress the downloads. I think that's what's being asked about.

Comment: I assumed the OP was asking about the upload because he asked about compression (vs the existing decompression on the downloads). May be wrong :)